# Shell script/regex to replace sentences except for a keyword in the middle (refactoring Angular directives)

Tags: regex, angular, shell, regex-lookarounds

I need to replace all Angular translation directives with those from ngx.

In short this means changing:

```
<dt i18n="test label@@testLabel">test</dt>
```

to

```
<dt [translate]="'testLabel'">test</dt>
```

Note the extra  **'**  that surrounds the label name.

It's fairly simple to just select **i18n="** and change it into **[translate]="'**  with a regex however my code will not compile then as my label will be missing a   **'**.

I continued to try a script

```
SomeText2="<dt i18n=\"testLabel@@testLabel\">Test</dt>"


REGEX_REP= echo $SomeText2 | sed 's/i18n="/\[translate\]="/' | sed 's/@@//'| sed s/\"/\'\"/2
```

But this will just put an apostrophe infront of every quotation mark.
So I think I'm looking for a regex that can check if there is a certain string ( [translate] e.g.) somewhere in front of it so I can replace **"** with **'"**.

Or if someone else has any better ideas let me know!
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEX_REP="$(echo "$SomeText2" | sed 's/i18n="[^"]*@@\([^"]*\)"/[translate]="'"'"'\1'"'"'"/')"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/f7VYg9), output is `<dt [translate]="'testLabel'">Test</dt>`.

The `i18n="[^"]*@@\([^"]*\)"` pattern matches `i18n="` substring, then `[^"]*` matches any 0+ chars other than `"`,  `@@` matches `@@`, `\([^"]*\)` captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `"` and  `"` matches a double quote.

The replacement is `[translate]="'\1'"`, that is `[translate]="'<Group 1 value>'"`.